# Display previous year and current year in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, date

I am trying to get the previous year and current year in the format "**2019-20**". Is there an easy way to do this. I have written a code but its returning 2020-21.

```
  getCurrentFinancialYear2() {
    var fiscalyear_ = "";
    var today = new Date();
    if ((today.getMonth() + 1) <= 3) {
      fiscalyear_ = ((today.getFullYear() - 1) + "") + "-" + (today.getFullYear() + "").slice(-2)
    } else {
      fiscalyear_ = (today.getFullYear() + "") + "-" + ((today.getFullYear() + 1) + "").slice(-2)
    }
    this.year_ = fiscalyear_
    
    return fiscalyear_
    
  }
```

Any easier way to achieve this?

Comment: why you are using `if` condition. because of if condition you are getting `2020-21`. because according to your if condition currentMonth + 1 = 9 which is greater than 3. that's why it is going in else condition and print 2020-21 as per your code.
otherwise your code block inside if condition will work as expected and will give you 2019-20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function getCurrentFinancialYear() {
  const thisYear = (new Date()).getFullYear();
  const lastYear = thisYear-1;
  return `${lastYear}-${thisYear.toString().slice(-2)}`;
}

console.log(getCurrentFinancialYear());
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're only concerned with modern years then you can just get the current year, subtract one and concatenate the last two digits of the current, e.g.

```js
function getFY(year = new Date().getFullYear()){
  return `${year - 1}-${String(year).slice(-2)}`; 
}

console.log(getFY());       // Default: current year
console.log(getFY(2021));   // Year as number
console.log(getFY('2022')); // Year as string
```

If you want to handle the full range of possible years (approximately ±285,426 from 1970), you'll need to do a little more work.

Comment: Lucky for me its the modern years. Thanks for the time mate :)